# How did "s***" and "the s***" come to mean opposite things?

Tags: etymology, slang

> [Your idea is shit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2h0uy1/whats_a_polite_way_to_say_your_idea_is_shit_even/)

*Your idea is bad.*

> [Your idea is the shit](http://thedesignkids.com.au/featured-magazine-cure/)

*Your idea is good.*

The same does not apply to "the crap" or "the poop", or other profanity like "the fuck".

I can think of examples where adding "the" to a noun makes it descriptive, like "the sux0rs" (bad), "the man" (good). I can't think of another example where a bad word is made good by adding "the".

Comment: How about "bomb" (bad if it explodes near you) and "the bomb" (good)?

Comment: Reminds me of this fun sentence: "An apostrophe is the difference between a company that knows its shit and a company that knows it's shit."

Comment: @SvenYargs similar, but different. The adj. **bomb** as in, "That meal you cooked last night was _bomb_" is positive, but the adj. **shit** is negative

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/why-the-opposite-meanings-of-the-word-bollocks

Comment: What about "bollocks" (in UK usage)? "That's bollocks!" versus "That's the [dog's] bollocks"... very similar scenario isn't it?

Comment: These things are acting mostly as intensifiers, so context as ever is key. And "Fuck!" even on its own can indicate good or bad, dependant on context and intonation.

Comment: Is “the man” really good though?

Comment: @You Depending on the context, yes, it is a compliment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like it is originated as a slang term for drugs, then gained a broader usage in time. Below is an excerpt from *The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English* edited by *Tom Dalzell*:

[image]

And here is the earliest usage of ***the shit*** as a drug in 1967 from the book *How to Talk Dirty and Influence People* By *Lenny Bruce*:

<sub>(the earliest usage I could find)</sub>

[image]

There is an *[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiznit)* entry related:

> The best. Originated as a term to describe high quality drug substances. IE, "this is good shit."
>
> Evolved to common usage for any item of high quality. However, in typical usage, the article "the" is required to denote superiority. Without the word "the" prefacing the word "shit," a different, usually negative, meaning applies.

There is also ***the shiznit*** but even *shiznit* is used instead of *the shit*.

> *shiznit*: More "urbanized" form of the shit. Basically means really, really good. Other versions include:hella cool,tight, the best. [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiznit)
>
> ---
>
> *the shiznit:*
> 1.something really cool.2.used to express joy in something/someone.3.to express that something is really or very good. [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+shiznit)

There is also a less common term, ***the junk***.

> The epitomy of being sick, dope, or tight. [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the+junk)

---

Note: One needs to be careful though, because ***the shits*** means *diarrhea*.

Comment: Bonus: _Egoism_ is defined as "I AM the shit!" in the _shit happens_ list in [_Maledicta, Volume 12_](http://aman.members.sonic.net/shit-happens.html).

Comment: So, if you use "shit" to mean drugs, then "the shit" would be good drugs in the same way that "the life" is a good life. So what you really want to say is "your idea is *the*", but you can't say "the" without a noun so you say "your idea is the shit".

Comment: When I was young (early 90's) shit either only meant excrement (or comparisons to it) or drugs. How and when it started being used for other things like "I am the shit" I think is a relatively new development.

Comment: @ermanen That's *egotism*, not *egoism*. At least, anyway, egoism defined as "I AM the shit!" doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you're saying drugs *are* the answer? Awesome!

Comment: *The stuff* can also refer to drugs, one of many situations when *stuff* and *shit* are interchangeable.