# Is "sh*t" rude, or can it be a compliment?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Is it rude to say *shit*? I heard someone say it today and I think they used it as a compliment.

I think they said this:

> You look shit.

I looked in the dictionary, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I would be very careful  with such vulgar words, especially as a learner. You can get unexpected reactions. And I think there are a lot of other expressions for compliments. For slang uses you should consult Urban Dictionary.

Comment: sorry, what does slang mean? I am new learning the English! ray William johnsons videos on youtube are helping me to learn,

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230399/how-did-s-and-the-s-come-to-mean-opposite-things) for more info.

Comment: See what George Carlin had to say about it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_dirty_words

Comment: Rather obvious troll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use it as a compliment is a cultural thing, and is usually said like this, coming after a **definite** article

> That video game is the shit!
>
> Your cooking is the shit!
>
> Winning money is the shit!

### It's impolite

To answer, your question, it is a bit rude and forward.  It isn't so much offensive as it is vulgar, though.  To use it in it's rudimentary form can be a bit unsettling for some.

> The dog just shit on the carpet

vs

> The dog just defecated on the carpet

---

**Shat** is the past tense of *to shit*, but it's very ironic to hear it conjugated as if it were appropriate in everyday formal speech.

Comment: I thought it was shat?????!

Comment: Right, but English is quite forgiving wouldn't you say?

Comment: maybe... I am unknown

Comment: Just because English is "quite forgiving" not sure that means deliberately teaching it "wrong" makes sense?

Comment: I believe that the [past tense](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shit) of *shit* is almost always *shit* in the parts of the U.S. I've lived in. It conjugates as *hit, hit, hit* rather than *sit, sat, sat*. It may be different in the U.K.

Comment: @Community Often variations are used for humour, e.g. shat, shite, shitted,  shitten (archaic). See also attribution to an animal: bullshit, horseshit, dogshit, etc. each of which has their own slightly different connotation.

Answer (score 10):

Generally, shit is an English curse word used to refer to human/animal waste (poop).  Instead of saying you have to poop, you can say you have to [take a] shit.  If you say somebody is a 'piece of shit', you are directly insulting them.  It's also used as a vulgar exclamation on its own, usually when something unexpected (and problematic) happens suddenly.

However, it can also be used positively or neutrally.  Colloquially, when you say something is 'the shit', it is a compliment.  'The shit' in this case means 'very good'.

Shit can also be just used as a replacement for the word 'stuff' or 'things', or as an intensifier.  If you say 'this is some good shit', you're really just saying 'this is some good stuff'.  As an intensifier, 'look at this shit' simply means 'look at this'.

Use of the word shit is **generally considered rude in civilized conversation**, and should never be used casually in a professional atmosphere, or among strangers (though this is not always followed).

Comment: In India, the word shit is generally not considered that rude, and is used similarly to the word 'muck'. You will overhear mothers tell their children to 'clean that shit off your clothes'.